# Let's Encrypt のインストール方法の違いについて

Tags: letsencrypt

**Let's Encrypt の自動更新がうまくいかないため、最初からやり直そうとしているのですが、下記の違いが分かりません**
・それぞれメリットデメリットは何ですか？

**[gitでインストール。自動更新する際、「○○-auto renew」とするやり方](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates/)**
・このやり方で試している人をネットでよく見かけます

**[公式ページ？に掲載されているやり方。certbot-nginxでインストール。自動更新する際は、autoなしの「certbot renew」](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-nginx)**
・このやり方で試している人はあまり見かけません

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certbot（旧 Let's Encrypt client）を使ってLet's Encryptから証明書の取得・更新を行う場合、[certbotの公式ページ](https://certbot.eff.org/)の方法で問題なくできるのであれば、公式ページの方法で十分だと思います。最近は、公式ページの方法で問題なく取得・更新ができるOSが増えています。

以前は、新しい機能を使いたいためにgitを使ってインストールしていたことがあります。そのため、ネットでの記事では、gitで試している人が多くなっていると思われます。

Certbotの証明書の取得・更新は以前よりも随分と簡単になって、もうネットに書く必要がないぐらいになっています。ネットの古い記事といっても今年の3月8日に Version 0.22.0 で ACME v2 に対応したので、それ以前のものを参考にする場合には注意した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

一つ目に挙げたページに記載の https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt にアクセスすると、
現在は https://github.com/certbot/certbot にリダイレクトされます。
両者の違いは情報の鮮度の問題だと思いますが、[Let's Encryptのガイド](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/)にも[Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)への導線が引いてあるので、こちらの手順に従えばよいかと。

「Let's Encrypt」は証明書を発行している機関の名前、「Certbot」はLet's Encryptから証明書の発行・更新を行うためのクライアント(の一つ)ですから、「Let's Encrpytをインストール」という表現は微妙に間違っています。